# Using Mongoose and MongoDB, can I combine a document update using req.body and an increment using $inc?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update a document using the inbound form fields from `req.body` without having to break them apart and build out a `$set`. I have this working just fine. Now I want to add an increment to a field that won't be provided by `req.body`, how do I do that?

Here's my current code:

```
var myproj = req.body; // grab req.body
myproj.foo = 'bar'; // some other random property

Project.update({_id: req.params.project_id }, myproj, { multi: false }, function(err, edited) {...
```

So how can I add a `$inc` to that for a field in the document called `version` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine modifiers in the same update and you can apply your whole `myproj` in a single `$set`:

```
Project.update(
    { _id: req.params.project_id }, 
    { $set: myproj, $inc: { version: 1 } }, 
    { multi: false }, 
    function(err, edited) {...
```